# JPopupMenu auto hide on JoptionPane Confirmdialog

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, jpopupmenu

I know that in order to prevent `JOptionpane` from hiding behind any of the frame we have to give the current frame as parent frame to `JOptionpane`.
   I have a `JTree` with popupmenu
   it has popup menu follows
    
Add
    
Rename
    
Delete
   when I click the delete menu i'll call the `showDeleteConfirmation()` to confirm the action to delete or not
   But the problem if I use currentMainframe(the one which jtree is present) as parent frame for `JOptionpane` and when I click the `JPopumenu` is not hiding(still in focus) so I have to click on `Joptionpane` once (to hide the popupmenu) and then only I can select the options
   
   If I use null as parentframe it is working perfectly(onclicking the the menuitem it is automatically hiding).

How to solve the issue

```
 //Have to click anywhere on JOptionpane to gain focus(also to hide popupmenu)
 public static Boolean showDeleteConfirmation() {
    if (deleteConfirmation) {
        int value = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(currentMainFrame, "Are you sure want to delete?", "Delete", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        return value == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
    }
    return true;
}


//This is working perfectly
  public static Boolean showDeleteConfirmation() {
    if (deleteConfirmation) {
        int value = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure want to delete?", "Delete", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        return value == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You say it's working perfectly with `null`, why not just do that? It is very difficult to understand the problem you are actually having from what you have said.

Comment: I think you haven't noticed my first line ...in order to prevent JOptionpane from hiding behind any of the frame we have to give the current frame as parent frame to JOptionpane..I want to handle that condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manually called `JPopupmenu.hide()` before calling that function.It solved the problem